# Index of an element in array

Tags: swift

For example, I have following class:

```
class Person: Any {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var surname: String = ""
}
```

Also, I have following array with instances of "Person" class:

```
let person1 = Person(); person1.name = "John"; person1.surname = "Smith"
let person2 = Person(); person2.name = "Ivan"; person2.surname = "Ivanov"
let person3 = Person(); person3.name = "Sam"; person3.surname = "Woodman"
let personList = [person1, person2, person3]
```

Is there a way of somehow getting indexes of all Johns?

Comment: Unrelated, but inheriting from `Any` makes no sense, since all types in Swift can be represented as `Any` and `Any` is not a real class, so no advantages come with inheriting from it. Moreover, why the dynamic keyword, are you using Realm? If you do so, you should give a real code extract, not a dummy one by substituting the inheritance from `Object` to `Any`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `flatMap` your list of persons as an enumerated list so to return the matching offsets.

```
let indexes = personList.enumerated().flatMap { $1.name == "John" ? $0 : nil }
```

Otherwise, you can achieve this with a simple for loop.

```
var indexes = [Int]()

for index in personList.indices {
    if personList[index].name == "John" {
        indexes.append(index)
    }
}

print(indexes)
```